# How to prove $\cos(x-\pi/2) = \sin(x)$ using Taylor Series?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Knowing that $\cos(x-\pi/2) = \sin(x)$ How can one algebraically prove both of the infinite series are equal?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n}\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(2n\right)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\left(x\right)^{2n+1}\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}$$

Comment: I think that one can prove the $\cos (A+B)$ formula algebraically, I am less sure that one can prove the Pythagoras result algebraically, but if so these will give that $\cos(x-\pi/2)=\sin x$. (If you allow differentiation of power series these two basic facts are pretty immediate; algebraically manipulating power series I am less sure.)